# What do the tallies on Captain Rex's armor represent?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, the-clone-wars, star-wars-rebels, armor

In the *Star Wars: Rebels* episode, "The Last Battle," Rex states that he doesn't keep track of how many droids he's destroyed like some clones did.

That got me thinking, do we know what the tallies on his armor refer to?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In an interview, showrunner Dave Filoni indicated that they represented "***kill marks***". Given that the volume is waaaaay too low for the number of B1-Droids we see him blasting on-screen, these presumably represent *significant* droid takedowns (such as Destroyers and Tanks) or he might just be counting in tens.

> *"He's like this veteran now and **he's got little kill marks all over his
> armor.** I think Rex is becoming something of a little legend. He's such
> a long term survivor of the Clone War"*.
>
> <sub><sup>[STAR WARS: THE CLONE WARS - WHAT'S TO COME IN SEASON 4](http://uk.ign.com/articles/2011/08/27/star-wars-the-clone-wars-whats-to-come-in-season-4?page=3)</sup></sub>

Comment: Notice how he ran out of helmet space and started using other armour pieces lol

Comment: @thegreatjedi Either that, or he's using different armor pieces for different types of droids - helmet for tanks, leg for destroyers, etc.

Comment: While this is definitely correct, it’s also pretty confusing. Why would Rex say that he never kept track of droid kills? He even has these tick marks in “The Last Battle.”

Comment: @Adamant He may have been specifically referring to regular battle droids only.

Comment: "tens" is a bit low. Maybe hundreds, for someone like him. Alternatively, it could be the number of droid companies/battalions he has defeated over the years. Now those numbers feel more realistic. Those clankers are easy to kill but are everywhere! Why are we counting them individually? It makes more sense to count entire units! Remember, he's a ground fighter, not a pilot. Different realities.

Comment: In WW2, it was common practice to put marks on aircraft to mark enemies planes shot down. Perhaps Rex has done the same, maybe it's a number of ships or a specific type of droid (destroyers)?

Comment: could it be that it was not kills but survived missions he ticked off?

Comment: @Thomas - "Kill marks" is the quote

Answer (score -1):

It's not the number of droids he's killed, it's the number of men he's lost. In the beginning of the series he only has a couple marks and is more lively and has more personality; towards the end he has a lot more marks and is a lot more grim and cynical because of how many men he has lost.

Comment: Do you have a source for this? Because his kill count also grew as the series progressed.

Comment: That's a pretty cynical take on things, but I really like that interpretation.